# Where are the new passkeys in the keychain?

Tags: macos, keychain

I have been playing around with the passkeys and I was expecting to see them in my keychain but no luck? Are they not visible to the user or are they in some menu that I cannot spot.

Answer (score 0):

They are not visible to the user in Keychain. The Passkeys are not passwords - contrary to how you normally login to web sites. Instead Passkeys means that a private encryption key is stored in the Keychain, and that is used to authenticate you against the server.

From the comments, I understand that your specific problem is that you want to delete a passkey. You can do this by opening `System Preferences` on the Mac, then click `Passwords`, and in the list click the web site, you have created the passkey for. From here you can click `Delete Passkey` and then confirm the deletion.

Comment: But the question remains, how do I find them in my Keychain Access?

Comment: @pedz what do you mean with „find them“? Which use cases do you have in mind?

Comment: @nohillside I am making some assumptions.  I assume the passkeys are stored in the Keychain.  So, if I go to site XYZ and create a passkey, I assume I can look in my Keychain to find it.  The particular use case is I am testing / creating a web site that uses passkeys and I'd like to be able to clean out all of the passkeys I create during testing.

Comment: @pedz Maybe asking a specific question about how to delete passkeys might yield better results then. There may be ways to delete them even though they can‘t be accessed directly via Keychain Access.

Comment: @pedz Even though the passkeys are stored in Keychain, you're not supposed to directly interact with it there. I have added to the answer here, how you can delete a passkey when you no longer need it anymore.

Comment: @jksoegaard Yes indeed!  I had a couple dozen for localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Passkeys are saved in the iCloud Keychain. Even thou they're visible in the regular Keychain Access app as password it's impossible to see the password value of a passkey. ~~

But you can always use Passwords panel in the System Settings or Safari Passwords Settings to manage them